# sed: -e expression #1, char 69: unknown command: `0'

Tags: bash, unix, sed, sh

I tried using the following sed command to replace a line in the file that I am reading .

```
sed -i "/$line/c\\${linerep}" "$1"
```

where $i is the input file where the lines are to be replaced.
I get the following error when I run the script:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 65: unknown command: `0'
sed: -e expression #1, char 69: unknown command: `0'
```

Please tell me what changes should i make in the sed command?
Is there any other way apart from sed to do the same operation?

Comment: Does your `$line` or `$linerep` contain slashes `/` ?

Comment: What are the sample contents of the 2 bash variables - `line` & `linerep`?

Comment: @user7073454: Are you planning to provide the information at all?

Comment: Ya, the contents of `line` contained `/`. So I replaced the `/` in sed command with `@` and now it is working fine